# how to use / include lpeg luapeg re module

Tags: lua, require, lpeg

ATM I'm trying to execute lua files from my application, this works with the basic lua. I'm using a borland compiler (builder 3, just don't ask >.<)

Now I'm trying to use lpeg via the re module. I've added the lpeg directory to the LUA_PATH environment variable. This directory includes re. lua, lpeg.dll from LuaForWindows and the *.c files.

Now when I try to start my script I get the error 
**error loading module 'lpeg' from file 'lpeg.dll':
lpeg.dll:1: syntax error near char(144)**

The same script runs perfectly in the IExecutor from LuaForWindows.

I guess I've setup my lua environment completely wrong. Where do I put the dll? Do I have to build it myself with my compiler? (tried, but failed)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add how borland builder 3 is being used in you project? Is it used to build your application? The lua interpreter? Was lpeg built with it?

Answer (score 4):

The error message hints that Lua tried to load a DLL as a Lua script. There are separate paths for DLL and for Lua libraries, don't mix the two.

In other words, if Lua finds a DLL using the path in `LUA_PATH` or `package.path`, it will try to load it as a Lua script. Put the DLL where it is found using `LUA_CPATH` or `package.cpath`.

Comment: Well there is no such thing as a lpeg.lua, so what is the standard re.lua trying to load?

Comment: @confusedandtired, see my edited answer. Tell us the contents of the paths mentioned in the answer and where the DLL is.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't have the LUA_CPATH variable yet.

I added it with the path for the dll. It looks like it's trying to load it now, but now I get an access violation in the lua5.1.dll when in luaD_call